# ggplot2: can't sort x axis by y value

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I have problem in sorting x axis by y value in ggplot2: here is the code below

```
#Data
hp=read.csv(textConnection(
"class,year,amount
a,99,100
a,100,200
a,101,150
b,100,50
b,101,100
c,102,70
c,102,80
c,103,90
c,104,50
d,102,90"))
hp$year=as.factor(hp$year)

#Plotting
p=ggplot(data=hp)  
p+geom_bar(binwidth=0.5,stat="identity")+  #
aes(x=reorder(class,amount),y=amount,label=amount,fill=year)+
theme()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

How do I sort my x axis by a c b d, which amount sorted by decreasing from 450, 290, 150, 90. What should I do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to give reorder the `sum` function, otherwise it defaults to using the `mean` function.  Then, I put a `-` in  front of `amount` to get the order reversed.

```
p=ggplot(data=hp)  
p+geom_bar(binwidth=0.5,stat="identity")+  #
aes(x=reorder(class,-amount,sum),y=amount,label=amount,fill=year)+
theme()
```

[image]