# R ggplot2 geom_bar barplot: order bars by count without modifying dataframe and where factor labels have a meaning

Tags: r, ggplot2

## Problem

My question is very simple, but apparently unanswered. I have a count barplot and I simply want to order the bars based on their count. However
1. I don't want to modify the original dataframe, that is unnecessary, and in more complicated examples it would be way too long to do.
2. I don't want to change the order without changing the actual underlying order of the labels. In the MWE below, for instance, I dont want to change the genres that artists belong to (which is what literally every other answer on StackOverflow suggests to do).

## Minimal Working Example

```
library(ggplot2)
# Create data
df <- data.frame(genre=c("Pop", "HipHop", "Latin", "Pop", "Pop", "HipHop"), artist=c("ArianaGrande", "ChrisBrown", "DaddyYankee", "EdSheeran", "LewisCapaldi", "ShawnMendes"))
# Plot
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=genre, fill=artist))
```

[image: plot]

How do I order the bars, keeping everything else the same? Surely this should happen at the plot level, not at the dataframe level, nor at the "input" level of ggplot.

Comment: I've already tried something like `newdf <- within(d, genre <- factor(genre, levels=names(sort(table(genre), decreasing=TRUE))))` and then using `newdf` instead of `df`. However, this works at the dataframe level. Surely this is unnecessary?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `geom_bar(aes(x= forcats::fct_infreq(genre), fill=artist))`?  This technically manually changes the factor levels n the underlying data but skips the step of doing this outside the plotting step.

Comment: "I dont want to change the genres that artists belong to" I don't know what you mean by this, since it isn't something I've seen in other posts

Comment: @camille basically I just want the third bar to become the first one, the first bar to become the second one and the second bar to become the third one.

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/30633741/5325862

Comment: @camille I think so.. let me study that for a bit

Comment: I think it works yes! Would you also be able to help me on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504838/plotly-r-with-ggplot2-use-coord-polar-in-a-geom-bar-using-plotly) question?

Comment: @Euler_Salter am I mistaken or the solution proposed by @camille involves editing the dataframe by adding a `count` column against which call `reorder`?