# Plotly R with ggplot2: Use coord_polar in a geom_bar using plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

Is there a **simple** way of using `coord_polar()` when doing a barplot in ggplot2 using plotly?

## Example without using polar coordinates - It works

One could also add `+coord_flip()` and this would still work.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
# Create fake data
df <- data.frame(
           genre=c("Pop", "HipHop", "Latin", "Pop", "Pop", "HipHop"), 
           artist=c("ArianaGrande", "ChrisBrown", "DaddyYankee", "EdSheeran", 
                    "LewisCapaldi", "ShawnMendes")
      )
# Create a ggplot bar plot in polar coordinates
p <- ggplot(data=df) + 
      geom_bar(aes(x=genre, fill=artist))
# Wrap it around plotly
ggplotly(p)
```

[image: plotly]

## What I need

When we add `coord_polar()` it stops working. Is there a workaround? I get the following messages

```
Warning messages:
1: In min(z[["x"]]$dimension %()% z$x.range %||% z$x_range) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(z[["x"]]$dimension %()% z$x.range %||% z$x_range) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(z[["y"]]$dimension %()% z$y.range %||% z$y_range) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(z[["y"]]$dimension %()% z$y.range %||% z$y_range) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: This is an open issue with the R plotly library: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/878

Comment: @Bas Thank you! I hope they'll fix it soon